# Error when I try to open SQL Server file (.sql) in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2022

When I try to open an `.sql` file (even if i have just created it), I encounter the following error `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Sql.Server.BatchParser.dll' or one of its dependencies`.

[image]

Exactly like in this 6 years thread about VS2015: [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42eeadab-585e-449e-beb1-0be22ec10c09/error-when-i-try-to-open-sql-server-file-sql-in-visual-studio-2015-editor?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Some info:

- Visual Studio 2022
- Windows 11
- SQL Server Data Tools **is** installed.

**Edit**: Reproduced with another computer and on another solution, but still on VS2022

Comment: Make sure you report it using this process as well. If you create a ticket you can link back to that here too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: I am also experiencing problems viewing a large 870 line stored procedure. The initial file open is blank until I adjust a splitter bar, whereas c# source files open as expected. Once the SQL source is displayed the vertical scroll bar does not work as usual, the thumb bar flickers and cannot be dragged. I am viewing the SQL source available here https://github.com/erikdarlingdata/DarlingData/tree/main/sp_PressureDetector

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, resolved by **uninstalling** the SQL Server Data Tools.

[image]

Comment: or temporarily disabling helped too

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Fixed like this:

Right click => Open With => Select another editor => Set as default => OK

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work, but I do like the functionality of SQL Server Data Tools.

Therefore, my workaround is to hit `Ctrl+Tab` twice, in quick succession (...assuming that I have more than one file open)

The act of changing context to another file, and then back again, causes the Sql Editor to sort itself out.