# how do I stop visual studio checking sql files

Tags: visual-studio

I have a visual studio project, which includes a directory with a bunch of migration scripts in .sql.   Trouble is these scripts are for a postgres database.

VS is opening those scripts, and finding hundreds of "errors" in them - which makes it very difficult to search for an actual error,  if I have a build problem.

In the perfect world they'd be validated as postgres scripts - but I'd be very happy with just the ability to tell visual studio "don't go anywhere near anything ending with .sql, for validation".   Is it possible to do that, in VS 2022 Professional?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948772/visual-studio-thinks-correct-sql-syntax-is-incorrect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128076/error-when-i-try-to-open-sql-server-file-sql-in-visual-studio-2022